# Angularjs not update $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble with my controller not updating Gui `$scope`.
After some research, I found out that you can use `$timeout`.

The service takes different time on different units and I do not want set like 5000 timeout because the app feels slow.
Is there any other way to do this?

```
.service('RowService', function ($q) {

var rows = undefined;
this.getrows = function (id) {
  var local = new PouchDB('db');
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  //      var rows = [];
  local.query(function (doc, emit) {
    emit(doc.type);
  }, { key: 'row_detail' }).then(function (result) {
    var rows = [];
    for (i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      local.get(result.rows[i].id).then(function (response) {
        if (response.orderid == orderId) {
          rows.push(response);
        }
        deferred.resolve(rows);
      })
    }
  }).catch(function (err) {
    // handle any errors
  });

  rows = deferred.promise;

  return $q.when(rows);
}

})


RowService.getrows($stateParams.id).then(function (data) {

    // Not working example
    $scope.rows = data;
    // Working example

  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.rows = data;
  }, 5000)

}
```

Comment: The `$timeout` function calls `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the timeout, so perhaps you can just call `$scope.$apply()` yourself after you assign `$scope.rows = data` ?

Comment: Why do you have deferred.resolve(rows); inside of your for loop?

Answer (score 0):

$scope.$apply() can sometimes lead to problems, but $timeout can be called without delay:

```
.service('RowService', function ($q) {

var rows = undefined;
this.getrows = function (id) {
  var local = new PouchDB('db');
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  //      var rows = [];
  local.query(function (doc, emit) {
    emit(doc.type);
  }, { key: 'row_detail' }).then(function (result) {
    var rows = [];
    for (i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      local.get(result.rows[i].id).then(function (response) {
        if (response.orderid == orderId) {
          rows.push(response);
        }
        deferred.resolve(rows);
      })
    }
  }).catch(function (err) {
    // handle any errors
  });

  rows = deferred.promise;

  return $q.when(rows);
}

})


RowService.getrows($stateParams.id).then(function (data) {

    // Not working example
    $scope.rows = data;
    // Working example

  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.rows = data;
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then don't provide timeout value it will work and the function will be called after all the functions have been executed. moreover you are suing promise in your service so you don't need a timeout value.